# How should I approach identifying multiple instances of specific shapes

Tags: opencv

I would like to identify [Set cards](http://www.setgame.com/set/rules_basic.htm) from an image using OpenCV 2.3. I can successfully use findContours to isolate the shapes: [image: SetShapes].

How should I encode the three shapes of interest and compare them to the image so that I can find them in different rotations and sizes?

I'm not asking for a solution, just suggestions on an approach to take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the left image, you can segment each card out.

Then try to use OpenCV matchShapes() to match these three shapes.

As matchShape() uses HuMoments, opencv doc described that Hu Moments are invariants to the image scale, rotation, and reflection except the seventh one...

You can also reference opencv's example code: cpp/squares.cpp to design your own shape matching program.

Comment: Thanks. I've played with matchShape() a little but it hasn't done a good job of distinguishing the oval from the squiggle. But I think that is the correct direction to take. I didn't know about the squares.cpp demo. I'll definitely see what I can learn from that. I did a quick test with my image on the left and it did a good job of identifying the cards.